# What is an alternative to using a hook inside a loop?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm using a library that provides a hook; `useSomething`. I'd like to loop some items that a user has selected dynamically, apply `useSomething`, and then do something else. I know that this is not recommended, and I know why it is not recommended, but what is an alternative or recommended way of leveraging this third party hook at the top of my function where it belongs?

```
import { useSomething } from "third-party-library"
import { useCallback, useState } from "react";

const MyComponent = ({ things }) => {
  const [selectedThings, setSelectedThings] = useState([]);

  const callback = useCallback(() => {
    selectedThings.map(thing => {
      const extendedThing = useSomething(thing); // Can't use hook in here
    })
  }, [selectedThings])


  return (
    <>
      {things.map((thing) => (
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            setSelectedThings([...selectedThings, thing]);
          }}
        >
          Select {thing.id}
        </button>
      ))}

      <button onClick={callback}> DONE </button>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Define the hook outside of the function with `const something = useSomething()` and call it inside the function.

Comment: But I won't know in advance what things to pass to useSomething, as the user has not selected them yet.

Comment: Is your useSomething hook, only allowing one thing at a time?

Comment: Probably already answered, but I came across this solution (linking here for posterity) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66687680/how-to-call-a-hook-function-into-a-map-in-react